# Status Bar App image is stretching when running. How to fix?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, image, cocoa

In my IB i have this:
[image]

It looks right and there's no problem. But when i run the app here's what i see:
[image]

It's stretching and it doesn't look right.
What could be wrong? Thanks.
I don't know if it matters, but i have a @2x of this image in the resource too.
Running on Lion.

EDIT: I changed the name of the image and it works fine now. Maybe it's a bug of Xcode.

Comment: It's not a bug, @2x resources are displayed half-size.
Accept the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try without @2 and check you plist to see if you changed anything.